# Run Keyword If not in Robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

Hi I want to run a keyword if some boolean is false, I am doing this to run a keyword if Bool is true but how can i run the keyword if Bool is false

```
Run Keyword If    ${Bool}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `Unless`.

```
Run Keyword Unless   ${Bool}
```

Comment: `Run Keyword Unless` is deprecated in version 5.0.

Answer (score 8):

Alternative - negate the bool value:

```
Run Keyword If    not ${Bool}
```